# INDE Multi-OS engine in android Studio

Tags: java, android, ios, intel

I want to use the new plugins INDE Multi-OS engine in my android studio,
I download and install, everything seems normal.
When I go to treat to use on android studio, nothing appears .. leaves create or to test the hello world.

that is not bad
as I add the plugins ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably Multi-OS Engine installer didn't install plugins for Android Studio correctly.

You can install Multi-OS Engine plugins manually. Go to  Android Studio -> Preferences -> Plugins and install two plugins from /Applications/Intel/multi_os_engine/intellij_plugins folder (you will see two zip files there) manually using "Install plugin from disk" button.